# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in true love exercise and I can't find problem

Tags: python, syntax

I am learning Python, and I have a problem with the code below. It looks like everything ok for me, but I have constant error. What is wrong?

```
#  Don't change the code below 
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this line 

combined_name=name1+name2
combined_name_lower = combined_name.lower()

t = combined_name_lower.count("t")
r = combined_name_lower.count("r")
u = combined_name_lower.count("u")
e = combined_name_lower.count("e")

true = t + r + u + e

l = combined_name_lower.count("l")
o = combined_name_lower.count("o")
v = combined_name_lower.count("v")
e = combined_name_lower.count("e")

love = l + o + v + e

love_score = int(str(true) + str(love))

if love_score < 10 or > 90:
    print(f"Your score is {love_score}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
elif love_score >= 40 and <= 50:
    print(f"Your score is {love_score}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {love_score}.")
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "constant error"? Are you getting an error message? If so, please edit the message text into your question.

Comment: e.g. `love_score < 10 or > 90` is **not** valid Python syntax. `>` requires two operands, you have to repeat the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've included the error message in your post:

```
  File "main.py", line 29
    if love_score < 10 or > 90:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The problem is the comparison syntax you're trying to use. It's supposed to be either

```py
    if not 10 <= love_score <= 90:
```

or

```py
    if love_score < 10 or love_score > 90:
```

Answer (score 0):

just a typo, correct with :

```
if love_score < 10 or love_score > 90:

elif love_score >= 40 and love_score <= 50:
```

Comment: Thank you. So it means that we have to constantly add variables in logic conditions. I thought ones is enough

Comment: cruel sarcastic world... :)